# Not able to see pdf content using href

Tags: angularjs

download pdf  usinmg this ma able to open pdf in new window but not able to see the content of file...could you please help me to get the content on file...
using Angular 1.4

Comment: <a ng-href="pdf/{{product.technicalDetail}}" target="_blank"> download pdf </a> using this am able to open pdf in new window but not able to see the content of file...could you please help me to get the content on file...
using Angular 1.4

Comment: same code working with Angular 1.6